# Why I get this error "invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'"

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

class A {
    int x;
public:
    A(int x) :
            x(x) {
    }
    A& operator+=(const A& a) {
        this->x = this->x + a.x;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a);

};

A operator+(const A& a1, const A& a2) {
    return A(a1) + a2;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a) {
    return os << a.x;
}

int main() {
    const A a1(2);
    A& sum = a1 + a1; // error**************
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

I get the following error:

> invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'A&' from an rvalue of type 'A'

But I don't understand what is the reason of this error.
At all, I get new object from `operator+` and I define a reference (`sum`) to this object , so what is the problem in this way? And how can I fix it?

Comment: The answer is in the error message: invalid initialization of **non-const reference**. Use const reference: `const A& sum = a1 + a1;`.

Comment: `a1 + a1` produces a temporary. A temporary cannot bind to a non-const reference.

Comment: @S.M. Hye , can you explain what is the problem to do it with non-const reference? Why I must with const reference?

Comment: Shortly: because you can not modify temp objects (rvalue). If you try to assign it to non-const reference, you tell to a compiler that you want to modify a temp object later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A operator+(const A& a1, const A& a2)
```

This returns a fresh object (an anonymous temporary) of type `A`.

```
A& sum = a1 + a1;
```

You try to bind this temporary to a (non-const) reference; thus trying to craft a reference to an object whose lifetime is about to end. Hopefully, this is not legal in C++. You really need to "*store*" this object somewhere:

```
A sum = a1 + a1;
```

---

A special case:

```
A const& sum = a1 + a1;
```

When a temporary is bound to a const-reference, the lifetime of this object is extended to the lifetime of the reference. This is useful for function argument, but not advised here.

Comment: In fact, what is defined as a "fresh object /  anonymous temporary" ? In other words , why in despite to the case in my question - the following code is valid ? : `A a1(2); A& s = a1;`

Comment: @Software_t Because you named `a1`. It lives in a scope and have a defined lifetime.

Comment: Ok , I know understand the concept, because that in my question it's rvalue so it's problematic , no?

Comment: An _rvalue_ is --- simplifying --- a temporary.

Answer (score 4):

A *reference* cannot bind to an anonymous temporary. And `a1 + a1` is an anonymous temporary.

Out of interest, a `const` reference can bind, so `const A& sum = a1 + a1;` is allowed. Furthermore in that particular case, the *lifetime* of that temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference (although it's important to note that this is not *transitive*).

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that MSVC14 actually allows binding temporaries to non-const references as an extension (which presumably includes lifetime extension). Not that you should do it, but maybe someone would be surprised Visual Studio is ok with it.